# docker rebase a layer into a new image?

Tags: docker, docker-build

In git, there's git rebase to take some commits and copy them on another branch.  This is a relatively light operation because the blob nodes underneath aren't duplicated, only the commit node on top is changed.  Is there such a thing for docker layers?  Can I `docker rebase ...` a layer onto another image?

Imagine I have a layer that adds a bunch of files.  (In this example we can assume it's always additive -- no changing files, no deleting files, only creating new ones where I'm confident nothing in the path existed previously.)  Imagine this layer is big and bulky.

Now I invalidate an earlier layer because I wanted to change an environment variable or change a line in a file on a lower-layer.  Of course when I next `docker build ...` it rebuilds from there on, so my new layer is rebuilt too.  Except the layer in question doesn't really change -- the hash changes, but the content doesn't.  I really don't want to push this layer to my docker repository and pull it to my production runtime.  After all, the previous version had all this content.

So can I `docker rebase` layer `abc123` from image `mything:v.old` onto `mynewbase:v.next` then tag it as `mything:v.next`?